PostgreSQL 17: Logical replication post upgrade from 13 to 17: Subscription is stopping on every single existing/conflicting row
I am using logical replication. I had upgraded from 13 to 17. There was a problem with existing subscriptions that were copied over from 13 as they would not work. I had to create new subscriptions.
The upgrade had copied all the table rows in the subscriber. These are existing rows in the tables that are the targets for replication. The state of replication does not seem to have been retained as a result every existing row seems to be a conflict.
I have executed ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub SET (disable_on_error = true); so that the subscription is automatically disabled on error.
I tried using ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub SKIP (lsn = '1/12345678'); and then ALTER SUBSCRIPTION sub ENABLE;. However, the replication stops on each conflict it finds. This is rather painful as there are a lot of tables with a lot of rows.
Is there a way for the subscription to skip all existing rows?

This seems to be answered in PostgreSQL logical replication - ignore pre-existing data

Suppose I truncate the tables and reset identity will I get the same ids in the tables as before?

Warning: If you are using logical replication please don't upgrade as I am now stuck with existing rows that I can't truncate. Other tables have foreign keys to these tables that I want to truncate. What a nightmare!

Had to remove foreign keys, start replication, and then put them back in with the same name I copied before deleting them. Have a script ready for the next upgrade.
